# Can Bamboo deploy to a server with only an internal IP?

Tags: development-environment, web-deployment, bamboo

All the Bamboo questions seem to be here, so here goes.

We have a development server that we would like to deploy to, using Bamboo OnDemand. It doesn't have an outwardly facing IP address, however. Our team cannot figure out how to get around this limitation.

Should this possible? What are the options to accomplish this?

Comment: Build automation is pretty well related to programming.

Comment: @AndrewMedico I'm pretty sure *server configuration* questions such as this one are off-topic.

Comment: @cybermonkey I think because it is at the half-way point between being a server issues and a programming issue(I would say code deployment is the responsibility of the programmer) that the majority of the Bamboo questions land here.

Comment: @nobrandheroes I'll ask on Meta, since this question is in the grey area of on-topic and off-topic.

Comment: @AndrewMedico Posted: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277562/are-bamboo-server-configuration-questions-on-topic

Answer (score 0):

This isn't much of an answer, but yes it is possible.

A VPN connection must be made from the agent(in our case EC2 and VPC) to the local network, but from what I am able to gather, it isn't too complicated.

*A Note: I haven't tried this yet. We are mostly likely going with Bamboo self-hosted just for ease of setup.*